# Define dependencies for framework controllers with Pimple

Tags: php, codeigniter, dependency-injection, frameworks, pimple

So I have a controller which I have added its dependencies with Pimple like this:

```
$this->container['Account'] = $this->container->factory(function ($c) {
    return new Account(
        $c['Menu_builder']
    );
});
```

And when I go to the URL of any action in this controller it just says:

```
Message: Argument 1 passed to Account::__construct() must be an instance of Menu_builder, none given, called in website/system/core/CodeIgniter.php on line 482 and defined Filename: controllers/Account.php Line Number: 13
```

To load any class with dependencies I usually say:

```
$account = $this->container['Account'];
```

But Im not sure where to put this call in the case of a framework controller.

The controller looks like this:

```
class Account extends MY_Controller
{
    private $menu_builder;

    public function __construct(Menu_builder $menu_builder){
        $this->menu_builder = $menu_builder;
    }
    // ...
}
```

QUESTION:
What am I doing wrong here? 
The above works fine for returning any classes except for controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not assigning a value to `$c['Menu_builder']` before executing `$account = $this->container['Account']`. Try assigning the controller to Menu_builder before instantiating Account class.